# Spring security CustomPermissionEvaluator not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

**MethodSecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses={EventWritePermissionEvaluator.class})
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration{

    private EventWritePermissionEvaluator eventWritePermissionEvaluator;

    @Autowired
    public void setEventWritePermissionEvaluator(
            EventWritePermissionEvaluator eventWritePermissionEvaluator) {
        this.eventWritePermissionEvaluator = eventWritePermissionEvaluator;
    }  

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler=new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(eventWritePermissionEvaluator);
        return expressionHandler;
    }
}
```

**CustomPermissionEvaluator**

```
@Component
public class EventWritePermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator{

    private ChecklistService checklistService;
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public void setChecklistService(ChecklistService checklistService) {
        this.checklistService = checklistService;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    public CustomUser currentUser()
    {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        CustomUser customUser=(CustomUser) userService.loadUserByUsername(auth.getName());
        return customUser;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication,
            Object targetDomainObject, Object permission) {
        Checklist checklist=(Checklist) targetDomainObject;
        Event event=checklistService.getChecklist(checklist.getId()).getEvent();
        String grp=event.getCreator().getGrp();
        System.out.println("event grp:"+grp);
        System.out.println("user grp:"+currentUser().getGrp());
        if(currentUser().getGrp().equals(grp))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication,
            Serializable targetId, String targetType, Object permission) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

**ServiceMethod**

```
    @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#ch,'write')")
    public Map<String, Object> updateState(Checklist ch, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws MessagingException 
    {

    }
```

The hasPermission() methods which i wrote in permissionEvaluator class are not getting invoked for incoming requests to service layer. Did i wrote anything wrong? i wrote some console statements in hasPermission() methods to see their execution. but i did not see anything in the console.

Thanks

Comment: In a Spring Boot project, I just had to annotate some configuration class with @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true), and create a PermissionEvaluator component class. Did not have to code a MethodSecurityConfig like yours. It's working well.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve? It seems like I can achieve exactly the same thing just by using UserDetailsService implementation from latest Spring Security.

This is my blog post about it

Implementing UserDetailsService:

http://www.yjsblog.com/2015/10/05/how-to-implement-custom-spring-security-authentication-with-userdetailsservice/

Implementing Role as property on an entity:

http://www.yjsblog.com/2015/10/05/userdetails-role-from-database-or-as-an-entity-property/

Please have a look at above links.
Cheers,